# Django: Filter records based on one to many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have following models,

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class InsuranceProfile(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       ...


class ProductExpertiseMaster(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'product_expertise_master'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    main_category = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class UserProductExpertise(models.Model): 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    product_expertise = models.ForeignKey(ProductExpertiseMaster, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

So what I am trying to do is I want to filter records based on various fields some of the belong to User model & some of them belong to the `InsuranceProfile` model.I am filter the records based on User & `InsuranceProfile` model which is working fine. Now i want to add one more filter which will be based on the `UserProductExpertise` model.**I want to get all the InsuranceProfiles with User details who have some matching condition with product expertise entries in `UserProductExpertise` model**. Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this using [`__isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#isnull):

```
InsuranceProfile.objects.filter(user__userproductexpertise__isnull=False)
```

It will return all the users who has an entry in in `UserProductExpertise` model. For querying, you need to use all lowercase of the model name, (ie `userproductexpertise`) and add `__isnull` at the end of it.

Comment: I think I have to re-phrase my question.I am already applying filter on the InsuranceProfile model with User model, & I want to add UserProductExpertise model filer. My final output shoould be all the entries which matches with all three model.Hope this clears it or let me if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make some changes in your models before proceeding further.

UserProductExpertise model is the bridge table between ProductExpertiseMaster and User, which provides a many-to-many relationship. If you won't add additional fields to UserProductExpertise model, you can drop it and define user relation in ProductExpertiseMaster model.

If you prefer using seperate model for this relationship, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING is prone to errors, you can change it to models.CASCADE

Here is an example with many-to-many relation:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class InsuranceProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(("Content"), max_length=500)


class ProductExpertiseMaster(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'product_expertise_master'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    main_category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name=("Users"), related_name="expertises")
```

For filtering your query:

```
InsuranceProfile.objects.filter(user__expertises__isnull=False)
```